# Let popup appear when logging in to guest account

Tags: lubuntu, guest-session

When logging out from the guest account, all the files of the guest are deleted.

I like this behavior, but is there a way to show a popup like "Warning, all your files will be removed when turning off the computer or logging out, better move them on an USB-stick first" when a guest logs in and/or out?

Also, are a guest's files really deleted or are they moved to a hidden place on the computer?

Answer (score 1):

Create a script using zenity, then autostart that script by putting a .desktop file for the script in /etc/skel/.config/autostart/.The script will run for all new users (copied to the user's $HOME). Because of this, you'll want to do a check on the username. It might look like this (warning, I haven't tested):

```
#1/bin/bash
if [ "$(whoami|awk -F- '{print $1}')" = "guest" ]; then 
zenity –error –title=”Guest warning” –text=”Warning, all your files will be removed when turning off the computer or logging out, better move them on an USB-stick first.”; 
fi
exit 0
```

You'll put that file somewhere accessible and set it to executable. You'll then create a simple .desktop file by looking at an example one and setting it to run the script you've just made, and place that in /etc/skel/.config/autostart/.

This is a great idea and should be standard.